# Remove Authentication from Web api on Localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config

I have a OData web api on visual studio using the ADO.NET Framework. I am getting an authentication window on chrome, I removed the authorize parts from the controllers and web.config file, yet the window asking username and password is coming.

How to remove it ? 
[image]

My web.config file has

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms requireSSL="true" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="myService" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

which I removed but still authentication window is opening. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `None` as mode for [authentication-Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). The default value when you do not specify anything is `Windows`. More information about ASP.NET Authentication can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719553(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
<authentication mode="None">
  <!--<forms requireSSL="true" />-->
</authentication>
```